# ¿Cómo obtener el id actual del registro?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy haciendo el registro de usuario con el scaffolding auth de Laravel, y necesito obtener el `id` de ese registro actual para hacer otra operación, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera pero no lo logro, me dice que la variable `$id` no está definida: `Undefined variable: id`:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return $id = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

        dd($id),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Cómo se te ocurre que pueda hacerse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes:

- Justo después de crear el registro invocar el ID
- Obtienes el ID reciente por medio del método `latest`
- Le indicas el uso de `first` para que solo te retorne un valor
- Accedes al ID como propiedad

Así

```
$latestId = User::latest('id')->first()->id;
```

El método `latest()` hará inicialmente un ordenamiento descedente por la columna `created_at`, sin embargo si no la tenemos o con esta no esta funcionando obtener el último id deseado entonces podemos modificar un poco pasándole como argumento de dicho método la columna `id` así le diremos que nos entregue un valor ordenando por la llave primaria.

Esta acción te regresará el ID del último registro hecho.

Edcición final, esta sería la sintaxis completa para obtener el valor deseado:

```
Modelo::create([
    'propiedad1' => 'valor1',
    'propiedad2' => 'valor2',
]);
return Modelo::latest()->first()->id;
```

Comment: Lo hice pero me muestra el anterior al que estoy guardando

Comment: Ejemplo guardo el registro con id 4, al iniciar un nuevo registro (en este caso id 5) y quiero obtener el id con el código que me suguieres me muestra el id 4

Comment: Sí tiene las columnas created_at y updated_at, de hecho es el auth que tiene Laravel por defecto. En mi migración esta: $table->timestamps();

Comment: Quizás podría estar bien que devuelva el anterior, porque aún no se ha guardado el registro cuando se ejecuta la línea:  $user = User::latest()->first()->id o sí?

Comment: Voy a intentar así a ver, con la última instrucción tampoco funcionó

Comment: Sí tengo la instrucción create sin el return debería funcionar, no? es que no sé como colocar el return después pero intenté sin el return y me sigue mostrando el anterior

Comment: Gracias, funcionó pero debo abrir una nueva pregunta para resolver el return, no necesito retornar el id sino usarlo para asignar un rol a un usuario y luego que me lleve a la web del panel de control

Answer (score 4):

No utilizo `create` para crear un nuevo registro pero el `id` debería de estar en el objeto creado, de esta forma:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
    ]);
    return $user->id;
}
```

Por lo general utilizo `save` para almacenar los datos, y lo que indique anteriormente si funcionaria:

**Ejemplo de como lo hago:**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user =new User();
    $user->name=$data['name'];
    $user->email=$data['email'];
    $user->password=Hash::make($data['password']);
    $user->save();//almaceno el dato
    return $user->id;//y estoy seguro que esto funciona.
}
```

Espero te sirva para futuros codigos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si pero ya te había calificado BetaM... Gracias a ambos!