# ¿Cómo obtengo el último ID insertado usando Laravel?

Tags: laravel, model, registro

Tengo un problema usando uno de los modelos de *Laravel*.

Quiero tomar el último registro del que se tenga el `user_id` para hacer más operaciones con ese objeto. ¿Cómo se hace esto?

```
Model::whereUserrID(1)->latest()->first();
```

No marca errores.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo obtener el id actual del registro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376357/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-el-id-actual-del-registro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que en tu función `where` estás tratando de buscar una propiedad llamada `userr_id` la cual no existe.

El resto de tu sintaxis está correcta, usando esto:

```
Model::whereUserId(1)->latest()->first();
```

O esto:

```
Model::where('user_id', 1)->latest()->first();
```

Deberías de resolver tu problema

Comment: Esta sintaxis `whereUserID` si el OP sigue las convenciones tiene un error de sintaxis

Comment: Sí era un error, se me fe una r de más en el where, ya funciona bien :) Muchas gracias @NoobDev

Comment: Qué es OP? @Beta

Comment: El *original poster*, en este caso tu el autor de la pregunta @SalvadorAndrade ;)